# Could not find a correct inverse value of a matrix by using numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I tried to use numpy to solve a matrix inverse, but could not get it to work.
The Python code is shown below:

```
import copy
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import *

K=[[0.13535533905932737, -0.03535533905932737, 0.0, 0.0, -0.1],       
   [-0.03535533905932737, 0.13535533905932737, 0.0, -0.1, 0.0], 
   [0.0, 0.0, 0.13535533905932737, 0.03535533905932737, -0.03535533905932737], 
   [0.0, -0.1, 0.03535533905932737, 0.13535533905932737, -0.03535533905932737],
   [-0.1, 0.0, -0.03535533905932737, -0.03535533905932737, 0.13535533905932737]]

newK = np.array(K)
newK = inv(newK)
```

And the result is shown as:

```
[[ -2.74615429e+16  -2.74615429e+16   1.89368970e+00  -2.74615429e+16
   -2.74615429e+16]
 [ -2.74615429e+16  -2.74615429e+16  -1.37357926e+00  -2.74615429e+16
   -2.74615429e+16]
 [  9.23495156e-01  -1.84699031e+00   8.84484598e+00  -3.69398063e+00
    1.84699031e+00]
 [ -2.74615429e+16  -2.74615429e+16  -2.52873329e+00  -2.74615429e+16
   -2.74615429e+16]
 [ -2.74615429e+16  -2.74615429e+16   3.04884372e+00  -2.74615429e+16
   -2.74615429e+16]]
```

I also tried using MATLAB to check this value, but it turns out that:

```
    a =

    0.1340   -0.0350         0         0   -0.1000
   -0.0350    0.1350         0   -0.1000         0
         0         0    0.1350    0.0350   -0.0350
         0   -0.1000    0.0350    0.1350   -0.0350
   -0.1000         0   -0.0350   -0.0350    0.1350

>> inv(a)

ans =

   1.0e+03 *

   -1.0000   -1.0000    0.0000   -1.0000   -1.0000
   -1.0000   -0.9808   -0.0033   -0.9841   -0.9967
    0.0000   -0.0033    0.0089   -0.0044    0.0011
   -1.0000   -0.9841   -0.0044   -0.9785   -0.9956
   -1.0000   -0.9967    0.0011   -0.9956   -0.9911
```

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Where is the `numpy` code where you invert the matrix?

Comment: Sorry for that mistake. I have edited it.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, the two matrices for the two programs are not identical:

numpy:

```
In [295]: np.linalg.det(newK)
Out[295]: -4.5051744884111939e-21
```

matlab:

```
>> det(a)
ans =
    -1.067499999999957e-07
```

Using the same matrix in numpy:

```
In [296]: K2=np.array([[0.1340, -0.0350, 0, 0, -0.1000],[-0.0350, 0.1350, 0, -0.1000, 0],[0, 0, 0.1350, 0.0350, -0.0350],[0, -0.1000, 0.0350, 0.1350, -0.0350],[-0.1000, 0, -0.0350, -0.0350, 0.135]])

In [297]: np.linalg.det(K2)
Out[297]: -1.0674999999999714e-07
```

And the inverse comes out right:

```
In [298]: np.linalg.inv(K2)
Out[298]: 
array([[ -1.00000000e+03,  -1.00000000e+03,  -2.93090593e-14,
         -1.00000000e+03,  -1.00000000e+03],
       [ -1.00000000e+03,  -9.80796253e+02,  -3.27868852e+00,
         -9.84074941e+02,  -9.96721311e+02],
       [ -5.26327952e-14,  -3.27868852e+00,   8.85245902e+00,
         -4.42622951e+00,   1.14754098e+00],
       [ -1.00000000e+03,  -9.84074941e+02,  -4.42622951e+00,
         -9.78501171e+02,  -9.95573770e+02],
       [ -1.00000000e+03,  -9.96721311e+02,   1.14754098e+00,
         -9.95573770e+02,  -9.91147541e+02]])
```

Secondly, the matrix in your numpy case is practically singular, its determinant is `1e-21`. This means that its inverse doesn't exist, and is horribly ill-defined at best (explaining the matrix elements of magnitude `1e16`) in the result.

Note that the difference between the matrices cannot be handwaved away saying that "*internally the two matrices are the same, only matlab didn't write as many decimal places*", since a matrix element of numpy `0.13535533905932737` is printed as `0.1340` in matlab, which is clearly wrong, irrespective of printing precision.

Also note that the only reason your matlab matrix is not *that* singular is that most of its elements are `0.135`, but its first element is `0.134`. If you make this element become equal to the others (just like in the numpy case!), you get

```
>> b=a
>> b(1,1)=0.135
>> det(b)
ans =
     1.481453848484194e-21
```

There you have it. If your actual matrix is the one in numpy, then the solution is easy: don't invert it, since it doesn't have an inverse.

---

To convince you, consider a random matrix with the same pattern of elements as your `newK` matrix:

```
k1=np.random.rand()*2-1 #element [0,0]
k2=np.random.rand()*2-1 #element [0,1]
k3=k1+k2 #element [0,-1]

Krand=np.array([[k1,k2,0,0,k3],[k2,k1,0,k3,0],[0,0,k1,-k2,k2],[0,k3,-k2,k1,k2],[k3,0,k2,k2,k1]])
```

then you get

```
In [322]: np.linalg.det(Krand)
Out[322]: 3.3121334687895703e-17
```

meaning that any matrix with this structure will be singular.

Final proof using sympy:

```
import sympy as sym
k1,k2=sym.symbols('k1,k2')
Ksym=sym.Matrix([[k1,k2,0,0,k1+k2],[k2,k1,0,k1+k2,0],[0,0,k1,-k2,k2],[0,k1+k2,-k2,k1,k2],[k1+k2,0,k2,k2,k1]])
```

Then the symbolic determinant is

```
In [347]: sym.det(Ksym)
Out[347]: 0
```

Comment: Exactly what I found. The matrices aren't the same, and the first matrix is effectively singular: its condition number comes out as 2e16.

Comment: @MatthewGunn I first thought that it was simply due to the structure of the matrix (very few unique elements being permuted), but I couldn't get a zero-determinant matrix using random matrix elements in the same pattern (badly conditioned yes, singular no).

Comment: Looks like a 5x5, rank 4 matrix to me: `K(:,1) == -K(:,2) - K(:,4) -K(:,5)` where `K =  [0.1354, -0.0354,  0, 0, -0.1000; -0.0354, 0.1354,  0,  -0.1000,  0;0, 0, 0.1354, 0.0354, -0.0354;0, -0.1000, 0.0354, 0.1354, -0.0354; -0.1000, 0, -0.0354, -0.0354, 0.1354];` (i.e. his K matrix). It does not have full rank hence is not invertible.